# Django - How to make an upvote button?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Currently logged in users can upvote x amount of times. 
The idea of fixing it is to create a new model called Vote. And it will have foreignkeys for user and product. When someone goes to upvote, you check and see: 
is there vote object with this user id and product id, and if there is, you don't allow him to upvote again; and if it is not, then you can go ahead and create that, and just increase total_votes on one.
But actually, i ran into it and cant figure it out and solve.

So, there is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def summary(self):
    return self.body[:100]

def pub_date_pretty(self):
    return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voteproduct = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product, Vote
from django.utils import timezone

@login_required(login_url="/accounts/signup")
def upvote(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
         product.votes_total += 1
         product.save()
         return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Updates:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    unique_together(('user', 'product'),)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    try:
        Vote.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product)
        product.votes_total += 1
        product.save()
    except:
        product.save()
    return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Also, how should i change my .html file? I really cant understand what is going on. Looking forward to hear from u.

```
{% for product in products.all %}
<div class="row pt-3">
<div class="col-2" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id 
                                        %}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
<img src="{{ product.icon.url }}" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
<div class="col-7" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id 
                                        %}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
<h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ product.summary }}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('{% url 'upvote' 
    product.id %}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn- 
    block" name="btn1" value="upvote"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"> 
    </span> Upvote {{ product.votes_total }}</button></a>
</div>
</div>

<form id="get_redirect_url{{ product.id }}" action="{% url 'upvote' 
object.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

well if i were you i would do it like that :

```
#step 1  change votes_total from integerfield to manytomany field 
##models
class Product(models.Model):
    #other fields goes here
    votes_total = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="votes" ,)

#step 2 ; go to your views.py and copy paste the following :

from django.views.generic import RedirectView


class ProductVoteToggle(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args ,**kwargs):

        obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url() 
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.votes_total.all():
                # you could remove the user if double upvote or display a message or what ever you want here
                obj.votes_total.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.votes_total.add(user)

        return url_


   #step 3 : go to urls.py and paste add the following : 
    urlpatterns = [
        #other urls here
        path('vote/<int:pk>',ProductVoteToggle.as_view() , name="upvote"),
]
     #in your template remove that form and paste the following code : 
     <a href="{% url 'upvote' product.id %}>Click to vote<a/>
```

### when you are done it should work if it didn't past the error here and i'll let you know what you are doing wrong

Comment: And how i need to change my views.py ?

Comment: How should i use this class?

Comment: Great; results in the the same vote table in the database with less code. There's no `blank` parameter for `ManyToManyField` though.

Comment: Endre Both, what i should do in views.py with this code ?

Comment: in your views use the ProductVoteToggle it's a redirectview

Comment: I am not sure, that i understand how to use class. 
As i understand i should use it in upvote function, or not ?

Comment: @NikitaShuliak  just paste it  in your views and add the url and template if you want to learn more  check this [link]  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

Comment: I added my .hrml file, can u please help me with it ?

Comment: How to figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't use `Vote` at all. In `upvote()`, first try to create a `Vote` for the user and product:

```
try:
    Vote.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product)
    # consider using the name product instead of voteproduct
```

If it succeeds, increment the counter. If it fails, notify the user that they have voted already.

Obviously, you need a [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in `Vote`:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'product')
```

Comment: As i understand:

`try:
            Vote.objects.create(user=request.user, product=product)
            product.votes_total += 1
            product.save()
        except:
            product.save()
        return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))`

And models:
`class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together('user', 'product')`
Should be like this ?

Comment: Could you update you question with the new code? It's not readable in a comment.

Comment: Excellent; though you may want to differentiate the redirect based on whether or not the vote was successful. Also, no need to save the product if the vote count didn't change.

Comment: There is an error:  
>   name 'unique_together' is not defined

Comment: unique_together is a field on meta: `unique_together = (('user', 'product'),)`. Apologies.

Comment: There error is disappeared. But it doesnt work anymore. When i tried to upvote, it is not changing (i make a new account).

Comment: Then you need to debug: Where does the process fail, do you have the proper user and product objects to create a vote for, can you create Vote objects etc. etc.

Comment: What i should do with the code of LeLouch in views.py ?